# trying to get PHP to post string to a file

Tags: php

I'm trying to use PHP to send the values of a form, in the format of a list item which contains an image and a caption to be added to a textfile which is then read by another page. The image upload part works fine but the output of the php looks like
`<li><img alt= "  " src="  " > </li>`

when it should be more like `<li><img src="img/comics/sa005.png">Comic 5 -  </li>`

```
    <?php
//get item details
$title = $_POST['title'];
$alt = $_POST['alt'];
$caption = $_POST['caption'];
$location = $_POST['location'];

//file location
$file = 'listitems.txt';
// The list item to add to the file


$string = ("\n <li>" . $title . "<img alt= \" " . $alt . " \" src=\" " . $location . " \" > " . $caption . "</li>");

// Write the contents to the file, 
// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file, $string, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

echo "string = ";
echo $string;
?>

<form action="appendlist.php" method="post">
  <input name="title" type="textbox" placeholder="Title" class="form-control" ><br><br>
  <input name="alt" type="textbox" placeholder="Alt text" class="form-control" ><br><br>
  <input name="caption" type="textbox" placeholder="Image caption" class="form-control" ><br><br>
  <input name="location" type="textbox" placeholder="File location" class="form-control" >
    <br>
<input type="submit" value="Add Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you post code where the form values are being set?

Comment: Pasted it into the original post

Comment: Is that file called appendlist.php?

Comment: no, the form is on a file called admin.php, the script to write to the file is called appendlist.php

Comment: I tried your code on my local machine and it appears to work just fine.  The only change I made was I properly self-closing the `<img>` tag and removing spaces (both of which should not have anything to do with your problem).  File gets written to with the correct value and a `var_dump($string)` produces what it should.

Comment: do you think it could be a problem with my php.ini?

Comment: I would start by doing a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you are getting for form values and then go from there.  Also, do you have errors suppressed?  If so, turn error reporting on temporarily to see if PHP is kicking anything out that may be helpful.

Comment: var_dump($_POST); returns
array(1) { ["submit"]=> string(9) "Add Image" } string(37) "

Answer (score 0):

Your code is also right. but you should have remove extra blank space. if that is not work then another problem.

Answer (score -1):

instead of trying to escape the double quotes, try to just use single quotes where you need a string encapsulated

```
$string = ("\n <li>" . $title . "<img alt='" . $alt . "' src='" . $location . "' > " . $caption . "</li>");
```

Comment: I tested your code posting the values to the page itself and it works.  the problem seems to be elsewhere, such as in appendlist.php.